# avl tree in order traversal

Tags: algorithm, traversal, avl-tree

Let S be a dynamic set of integers. Let n = |S|. Describe a data structure on S to
support the following operations on S with the required performance guarantees:

• Insert a new element to S in O(log n) time.

• Delete an element from S in O(log n) time.

• Report the k smallest elements of S in O(k) time, for any k satisfying 1 ≤ k ≤ n.

Your structure must consume O(n) space at all times.

could i simply build an AVL tree and then preform in order traversal printing out first 3 elements?

Comment: `could [I] simply build an AVL tree and [print the first 3 elements using in-order traversal?` How much time would this take for a million elements? A million millions? A [Googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex)?

Comment: The standard answer is a balanced, threaded binary search tree. This is a BBST that uses the otherwise null pointers in leaf nodes. These connect the nodes in a something close to a linked list in sorted order. It runs out that you can maintain the pointers with only O(log n) additional time per insert or delete (constant time per node touch). The you can list the first k nodes on O(k) time by just traversing from the head of the list.  There's a rather beautiful implementation at http://adtinfo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested solution does not work in O(k) time. Starting an in-order traversal takes O(log n) time. Even when you stop after you find one element, you still need to get to the left-most leaf first.

I can think of two solutions:

1. Use a [skip-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), it has O(log n) insertion and deletion and the underlying list is sorted. However, the time complexity of the insertion and deletion is average and not worst-case.
2. Use a modified [AVL-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), keep a dedicated pointer to the left-most node and update it on insertions and deletions. Also nodes must have pointers to their parent node, so that you could do in-order traversal starting at the left-most node. Or use a [threaded tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).

Comment: An alternative to having parent references from way back when memory was scarce are [threaded trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree) - add references to left- and/or rightmost _node_ (not leaf) as needed.

Comment: would having these extra pointers violate the space constraint?

Comment: @101ldaniels It's a constant number of pointers per node - space complexity is still O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Use a priority queue, which uses O(n) space. Insert and delete are both O(log n) operations. Find-min is O(1), followed by remove-min which is O(k), which you can repeat three times.

Comment: in [priority queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Summary_of_running_times) remove min is O(log n)

Comment: You are correct. My bad. I'll leave this answer here as a reminder to myself not to be stupid.

Answer (score -1):

ive decided to store and updated left most node pointer at the root, and pointers to predecessor and successor at every node

thus on every insertion it costs O(logn) for insertions and O(logn)+O(logn) to find both predecessor and successor, O(logn)+O(logn)+O(logn) = O(logn)

these pointer also allow for the update of effected node pointers after insertion in O(1) to travel to predecessor or successor respectively and update there pointers also in O(1)

having pointer to left most node at the root means travelling there is O(1) and then traversing the successor and printing first k nodes in O(k) time.